# While implementing this code on my wp-admin the content is okay but in the customers views the slider is not okay and the image is strechd/ distorted

Tags: wordpress

/img/scrubber-pov.png" id="pov-robot" alt="Robot Perspective" />
    
    
        
            
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                " style="background: url();">
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                        /img/scrubber-pov.png" class="inside-slide-robot" alt="Robot Perspective" />

Answer (score 0):

/img/scrubber-pov.png" id="pov-robot" alt="Robot Perspective" />

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( have_rows('technology_slides') ):?>
    <div class="mobile-slider-presentation">
        <?php $slide_count = 1;
        while( have_rows('technology_slides') ): the_row(); 
            $slide_background = get_sub_field('slide_background');
            $slide_content = get_sub_field('slide_content');?>
            <div class="slide-background" id="slideNumber-<?php echo $slide_count;?>" style="background: url(<?php echo $slide_background['url'];?>);">
                
                <div class="container-fluid content-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-4 offset-xl-8">
                            <div class="slide-copy">
                                <?php echo $slide_content;?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/scrubber-pov.png" class="inside-slide-robot" alt="Robot Perspective" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $slide_count = $slide_count + 1;?>
        <?php endwhile; reset_rows();?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).